# In C#, how can I set the output file name to change with each iteration?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to write a small C# service that will convert .csv files into .xml.  I have done this without issue, however when outputting the files, I want each one to be differently named.  Ideally, I'd like the file name to be determined by one of the data items in the converted file, eg. Docket Number.  Is this possible? Or am I stuck with it constantly outputting the one file name.

Thanks in advance

The code I have so far is:

```
   string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("TrialCSV.csv");
            XElement cust = new XElement("Root",
                from str in source
                let fields = str.Split(',')
                select new XElement("Delivery",
                    new XAttribute("CustomerName", fields[0]),
                    new XElement("PlantName", fields[1]),
                    new XElement("Material", fields[2]),
                    new XElement("Volume", fields[3]),
                    new XElement("TimeLoaded", fields[4]),
                    new XElement("DocketNumber", fields[5]),
                    new XElement("PurchaseOrder", fields[6]),
                    new XElement("Hauler", fields[7])

                            )
            );

            cust.Save(@"C:\TrialOutput.xml");
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Otherwise it will be near impossible to give you a relevant answer.

Comment: You could add the current moment in time to make sure every file has a unique name. `DateTime.Now.Ticks`

Comment: **What have you tried?** File names are specified using `string` values. `string` values can be set **to whatever you want**. So, if you want a file name to be something specific, just use the various C# string formatting features (e.g. interpolated strings, `string.Format()`, concatenation, etc.) to build a `string` value that's exactly what you want. If you need help with that, post a question with a good [mcve] that shows _what you've tried_, and explain what _specifically_ you're having trouble with.

Comment: Apologies, I have amended my original question with what I have so far.  What I'm having trouble with is formatting the output name such that it will vary, and not overwrite or append the existing file.

Comment: So you basically jsut want to increment the file name by one? ie `<fileName>1.xml`,`<fileName>2.xml`

Comment: Ideally the file name would match one of the field values (the docket number) but if this isn't possible, then I'm happy to increment by one @MichaelRandall

Comment: I am assuming DocketNumber is same per csv file. In that case, you can read the docketnumber from any row and then save the file with this value. var basepath = "C:\"; var filename=<docketnumber>; cust.Save($"{basepath}\{docketnumber}.xml");

Comment: int index = 0; cust.Save(@"C:\TrialOutput" + index.ToString() + ".xml");